# PyPDF4 Error [PdfReadWarning: Superfluous whitespace found in object header]

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf4

```
import PyPDF4
path = f'C:/Users/Gabriel/Desktop/Curso/Teste/pdfs/teste/ABRAHAO.pdf'

pdf = open(path, 'rb')
reader = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(pdf, strict=False)
page = reader.getPage(0)
text = page.extractText()
text = text.strip()
```

reading a pdf file, I tested it with another 295 files and they went smoothly

Comment: I was giving this error before, then I added the strict and it does not return anything

Comment: It's not an error, it is a warning message. It say that the PDF does not follow the specifications, but that pypdf can deal with that.

Answer (score 2):

Add parameter "strict=false".
If this doesn't work then you can try using [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/), [tabula](https://pypi.org/project/tabula-py/) or [py-pdf-parser](https://pypi.org/project/py-pdf-parser/).